# Cassandra ODBC parameter binding

Tags: cassandra, odbc

I've installed DataStax Community Edition, and added DataStax ODBC connector. Now I try to access the database via pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver=DataStax Cassandra ODBC Driver;Host=127.0.0.1',
                            autocommit = True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Test (id INT PRIMARY KEY)')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (1)')
for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Test'):
    print row
```

It works fine and returns

```
>>> (1, )
```

However when I try

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (:id)', {'id': 2})
```

I get

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (:id)', {'id': 2})
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Alternatives do neither work:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (:1)', (2))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (?)', (2))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

and

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (?)', (2))

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (15) Error while preparing a query in Cassandra: [33562624] : line 1:31 no viable alternative at input '1' (...Test (id) VALUES (:[1]...) (15) (SQLPrepare)")
```

My Cassandra version is 2.2.3, ODBC driver is from https://downloads.datastax.com/odbc-cql/1.0.1.1002/

Comment: any reasons for using ODBC and pyodbc instead of a native driver?

Comment: Actually I want to access Cassandra from Delphi, and ODBC is pretty much the only option for me there. I used Python script here so more people could understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to pyodbc Documentation your query should be

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (?)', 2)
```

More details on [pyodbc Insert](http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/#insert)

As per the comment got a thread which says it is a open bug in pyodbc
[BUG](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/issues/35)

Comment: The result is the same, unfortunately:
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: Hmm, the code doesn't work with pypyodbc either: pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied'). Are there any alternatives to test Cassandra ODBC?